# Making Modal Wizard

Tags: jquery, wizard

How could i make a modal wizard with jquery??

Answer (score 9):

**JQuery Wizard Plugin**
http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2008/08/jquery-wizard-redux/

Demo is here:
http://jerodsanto.net/src/wizard/demo/

Very cool.

Comment: Then you can just put this in a div and use the Jquery dialog widget to make it modal. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 4):

Try Wizard plugin [here](http://www.noveltheory.com/Wizard/).

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-wizard is very nice!

Answer (score 2):

There are now several wizards available, which can be used in combination with a [jQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal).

[Stepy](http://wbotelhos.com/stepy)

[jQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org)

[Smart Wizard](http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/demo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery Wizard Plugin mentioned by Robert for the wizard and combine that with **[BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)** a good jquery Modal tool